# Alinear vertical y horizontalmente un comoponente/elemento React-js con elementos hermanos variables

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, position, mui

El proyecto está en base a ReactJS, usando componentes de MUI y algunas otras bibliotecas que ni tienen efecto en este fragmento de código.
Estoy buscando otras soluciones de las que conozco cuando me cruzo con estas incidencias a la hora de querer alinear elementos.
El problema consiste en que hay tres elementos en un contenedor padre con `felxDirection:'row'`, y el elemento hijo numero 2, el central se necesita que esté presente siempre y centrado vertical respecto a su contenedor y horizontalmente respecto a la pantalla.
Los dos elementos hermanos 1 y 3 son de ancho y existencia variable pues desconozco que ancho van a tener porque están en función del texto que les ingresa por prop y depender en que pantalla se los utilicen o no.
Este componente en si va a ser un `Header`, el cual es reutilizado en distintas pantallas, por ello que los botones son de existencia variable y dimensiones variables.
lo único fijo es un logo imagen del centro.
Este problema lo he solucionado conceptualmente de la siguiente manera (lo he resumido lo máximo posible para ser entendido graficamente, respecto del ejemplo real):

```js
// Contenedor principal
<Box 
  sx={{
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    borderBottom: '1px solid rgba(31, 36, 45, 0.1)',
    px: isMobile ? 0 : 5,
    pt: 2,
    pb: isMobile ? 0 : 2,
  }}
>

  {/* Elemento padre 2 */}
  <Box
    sx={{
      display: 'flex',
      flexDirection: 'column',
      flex: 1,
    }}
  >
    //-----------------------------------------------------
    {/* Elemento padre 3 */}
    <Box 
      sx={{
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        position: 'relative',
        height: isMobile ? '40px' : '48px',
        pb: isMobile ? 2 : 0,
      }}
    >
      //=============================================
      {!hideButtons && onBackButton && (
        <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', flex: 0 }}>
          {/* Elemento hijo 1 */}
          <Box>Contenido del elemento hijo 1 BOTÓN ANCHO Y ALTO VARIABLE</Box>
        </Box>
      )}
      //=============================================
      <Box 
        sx={{
          position: 'absolute',
          top: isMobile ? '30%' : '50%',
          left: '50%',
          transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
        }}
      >
        {/* Elemento hijo 2 */}
        <Box>Contenido del elemento hijo 2  IMAGEN A CENTRAR</Box>
      </Box>
      //=============================================
      <Box>
      {/* Elemento hijo 3 */}
      <Box>Contenido del elemento hijo 3 BOTÓN ANCHO Y ALTO VARIABLE</Box>

    </Box>
    //-----------------------------------------------------

    {isMobile && !hideButtons && onBack && protectedStartOnly && (
      <Box></Box>
    )}
  </Box>
</Box>
```

Lo que hice fue utilizar `position:relative` sobre el padre y `position:absolute` sobre ese hijo a centrar sin depender de los hermano.
Esto conlleva una montaña de posibles problemas.

Aunque puede funcionar visualmente, hay que tener en cuenta estos puntos:

1. Dependencia del tamaño y posición del padre relativo (que puede no ser el contenedor)
2. Dificultad para mantener la posición
3. Problemas de superposición y z-index
4. Problemas de navegación por teclado
5. Accesibilidad y lectores de pantalla, al alterar el orden lógico.

Entonces quiero obtener la forma de no depender de estas soluciones pues ni se me ocurre al momento otra solución.
Muchas gracias por la atención de antemano.